# RapidMiner Sentiment Analysis 

Tags: string, machine-learning, weka, text-mining, rapidminer

I have a collection of short messages classified as positive or negative which is saved in an ARFF file genereated in WEKA. I would like to move this data to RapidMiner for classification and processing purposes.

Being a complete newbie in RapidMiner does anyone have examples on how to build a classifier for these messages. The messages are in one file in the format:

```
"MSG 1 TEXT", categoryX
"MSG 2 TXT", categoryX
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of rapidminer videos here:

http://www.youtube.com/user/VancouverData?ob=0&feature=results_main

There is a series on text mining